# Error building war file with ant in olio setup

Tags: ant, glassfish-3

I'm currently installing olio using the olio_java_setup:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/olio/docs/java_setup.html

I installed within the setup JDK 1.7, ANT 1.8.3, FABAN 1.0.1 and Glassfish v3.
I finished all previous steps of the setup and i am stuck in step 7 of Building the Web Application.
When i enter the "ant" command in the terminal the Build fails with the following output:

```
foo@ubuntu:~/olio/webapp/java/trunk/ws/apps/webapp$ ant
Buildfile: /home/foo/olio/webapp/java/trunk/ws/apps/webapp/build.xml

default-ear:

init:

-pre-compile:

bpp-actual-compilation:
     [echo] Compiling webapp
    [javac] /home/foo/olio/webapp/java/trunk/ws/bp-project/command-line-ant-tasks.xml:96: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 9 source files to /home/foo/olio/webapp/java/trunk/ws/apps/webapp/build/classes

BUILD FAILED
/home/foo/olio/webapp/java/trunk/ws/bp-project/command-line-ant-tasks.xml:96: /home/foo/olio/webapp/java/trunk/ws/apps/webapp/${javaee.lib.dir} does not exist.
```

Can somebody please tell me where my mistake is and how can I fix it?

Kind regards,
Kim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may have missed some steps when setting up the properties in previous steps.  The message you are getting indicates that a path cannot be found, but in that path is an unassigned property, ${javaee.lib.dir}.  When you see this in ant output, it means that there is a property named javaee.lib.dir that is is trying to use as part of the path that has not been assigned a value.  You'll have to find out why that variable is not getting assigned a value by looking for it in one of the .properties files or the build.xml.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I added ${javaee.lib.dir} to the build file and now it works. But it was not part of the previous steps, so it is missing in this setup !!!

Answer (score 0):

Olio doesn't support JDK 1.7 yet, check the Olio developer's response [here](https://github.com/shanti/olio/issues/3#issuecomment-16132805)